# Problem accessing PayPal form variable 

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get this post value of this variable, but I can't access it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="url">
```

I've tried `$_POST['on0']` but it's not working

Comment: Are you using POST or GET in the form?

Answer (score 1):

If the form action is POST then using `$_POST['on0']` should work. (If the action is GET, you'll need to use `$_GET['on0']`.)

If neither of these are working, then it's likely that there is no value stored (i.e.: that the "url" is blank) or that the element name isn't "`on0`".